# Postgresql pgadmin log can't work

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

```
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/status.html
```

Hi, I have one server can activate this function, it means I can see the server log in my PGADMIN tool, but I don't know why other servers can't.

I follow the instructions on this official page.

```
log_destination = ‘stderr’ 
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_file_mode = 0600
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_filename = ‘postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log’
```

But the tool still shows "Logs are not available for this server"

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Login postgres DB, then load the extension, it works!

```
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```